# How to correctly override onMeasure() and give a min height if height is LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to override `onMeasure()` method in my custom `View`. And if user specify height to be `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` then I want to give a particular minimum height. Right now my custom `View` takes up the whole screen with both `WRAP_CONTENT` as well as `MATCH_PARENT`, unless height is specified explicitly. I was thinking of checking `LayoutParams` in `onMeasure()` when I stumbled upon this code in `View` class:

```
  /**
 * The layout parameters associated with this view and used by the parent
 * {@link android.view.ViewGroup} to determine how this view should be
 * laid out.
 * {@hide}
 */
protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;
```

Despite being protected it is not accessible in custom `View` class, noticed the `@hide` annotation in comment? Although I can get this by calling `public` method `getLayoutParams()` but now I am wondering is `onMeasure()` the right place for the checking of params and assigning min height value? My current `onMeasure()` looks like this.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
            heightMeasureSpec);
    final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            widthMeasureSpec);
    int w = resolveSize(width, widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = resolveSize(height, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read source code and solved my problem by giving min width and min height to `resolveSize()` method. Which solved my problem:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); 
    int w = resolveSize(myMinWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = resolveSize(myMinHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h); 
}
```